# How can I prove this about the tangent line formula??

Tags: abstract-algebra, derivatives, polynomials

The equation of a tangent line to $f(x)$ at $x = t$ is $y = f'(t)(x - t) + f(t)$. Recently, I heard that it is also determined by the remainder of polynomial division of $f(x)$ by $(x-t)^2$.

For example, let $f(x) = 3x^3 + 2x^2 + x + 1$, then the tangent line of $f(x)$ at $x = 1$ is $y = 14(x-1)+7$, because of
$$ \frac{f(x)}{(x-1)^2} = \frac{(3x+8)(x-1)^2 + \color{red}{14(x-1)+7}}{(x-1)^2}. $$

BUT I can't prove this for $n$-th degree function. Please prove it. Thank in advance.

Comment: You probably want $\;k=t\;$ according to your notation?

Comment: @Timbuc Thanks for pointing out typo. I fixed it.

Comment: It is valid if $f$ is a polynomial. This is because Taylor's formula is an *exact* formula for polynomial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: For a polynomial function $f$ and a fixed $t$, consider the polynomial division

$$f(x) = (x-t)^2 q(x) + a(x-t) + b.$$

Now evaluate at $x = t$ to find $b$, then differentiate and evaluate at $x = t$ to find $a$.